# replace an already created instance in spring with the one created at runtime

Tags: spring

I have a Spring framework related query.

Could you pls help me in getting this problem resolved.  My requirement is to replace an already created singleton instance with the one which is created at runtime programmatically.

I have a spring context defined in bean as follows:

```
<bean name="configuration"   
   class="com.myapp.tests.ServiceConfiguration" />  

<bean name="anotherBean class="com.myapp.tests.AnotherBeanClass">
     <property ref="configuration"/>
</bean>
```

And i am loading the the context using

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ClassPathXMLApplicationContext("appConfig.xml");
```

I need to create a new instance of com.myapp.tests.ServiceConfiguration and replace "configuration" at runtime   and load the other beans which have a dependency on this( kind of refresh.). In our case, anotherBean should see the newly created ServiceConfiguration instance after i re-register the singleton.

Could you pls kindly post a solution as i am new to this sort of spring requirements. I get an error if i try to registerSingleton as it says this bean cant be registered as its already there. Error infact is correct, but i need this sort of capability to the application.

THanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How do you want to create the new instance? Do you use `new`?

Comment: Actually i am making use of dropwizard framework. Dropwizard framework gives me this object. I will  have to inject into spring beans. Thanks for your reply

Comment: assuming if its created via new, could you pls let me know how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
 BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
 GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
 MutablePropertyValues values = new MutablePropertyValues();
 values.addPropertyValue("property1", "abc");
 values.addPropertyValue("property2", new RuntimeBeanReference("beanFromContext"));
 beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(values);
 beanDefinition.setBeanClass(ServiceConfiguration.class);
 beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
 registry.registerBeanDefinition("configuration", beanDefinition);
```

Comment: But this doesn't use my new instance to set to configuration. my intention is create an instance of ServiceConfiguration as: ServiceConfiguration sc= new ServiceConfiguration(); //do some logic to set some properties on sc. Then replace in the spring context the ref pointed by bean id "configuration" to sc object instance

Comment: @vensai updated my answer to show how to set properties (string and another bean from context)

Comment: hi wdeens, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Do you have an option like replace an existing instance without using BeanDefinition ? Something similar to the following: context.registerSingleton("configuration", sc); context.refresth(); I agree register will throw an error since its already defined. But any api just to replace the existing bean with my instance ?